# Button drawable top is too small

Tags: android, button, drawable

I have a button, the png icon for which is of the size 200x200px

yet the icon on the button itself is very small

this is my code for the button

```
<style name="buttonMenuAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">@drawable/selector_menu_text_color</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">10sp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:drawablePadding">@dimen/space_between_menu_icon_and_text</item>
</style>



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSendToFriend"
        style="@style/buttonMenuAppearance"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/selector_settings_ic_sendtofriend"
        android:text="Recommend" />
```

yet the icon on the button is too small, its no where near 200 px high

and this is what it looks like

[image]

after editing the height of the button to be 200dp this is what i get
[image]

How to make the drawable bigger?

Comment: how to make the drawable bigger

Comment: Have You tried to use 9-patch (http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html)? It probably will ensure proper scaling and You'll not need to set padding programmatically.

Comment: it is an icon, this one looks like an envilope, but the other ones cant really be streched, 9patch does not scale the image, it stretches it by duplicating pixels

Comment: So, do You want to have 200x200 buttons with that top drawable? And if set button height (using android:layout_height?) you observe some cropping as in second image, right? Could You share xml used for buttons?

Comment: please see question body for xml used

Comment: It's only single button, but on your last image - there're two buttons and it looks like 'recommend' one get overlapped by above one 'edit details'.

Comment: edit details is beside the point here, i wanted to prove that changing the button height, did not affect the size of the drawable, it seems that the person who suggested i change the button height has deleted his comments, there were 3 or 4 comments before yours on this question a few days ago.

Comment: If You're talking about top drawable, then yes, I believe it doesn't depend on buttons height.